# How to center image inside of an li?

Tags: html, css

I have this html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="event.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="header-container">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-content">
                    <h1 class="heading">
                        Test
                    </h1>
                    <ul class="heading-list">
                        <li>Sell<img src="money.png"></li>
                        <li>Buy<span><img src="tickets.png"></li>
                        <li>Sign in<span><img src="locked.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this css below:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #F6F8F9;
}

.header-container {
    background-color: #260354;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-content {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading-list {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.heading-list li {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.heading-list li img {
    color: white;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In the navigation list on the top right (`ul`) I want to center those images with the `li` text in my css. I tried putting `text-align: center;` on the `.heading-list li img` but it is not centering the image. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: unclosed `<span>` tag

Comment: how do you mean by centering the images though? they're in `li` tags with text so text is placed on the left and image on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox, as I used in this example

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #F6F8F9;
}

.header-container {
    background-color: #260354;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-content {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading-list {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.heading-list li {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.heading-list li img {
    color: white;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="event.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="navigation-content">
        <h1 class="heading">
                        Test
                    </h1>
        <ul class="heading-list">
          <li>
            <span>Sell</span>
         <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3038657495/3d2f325c92060a35e7ac8c697c57d8d4.jpeg">
         </li>
       <li>
       <span>Buy</span>
         <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/630664501776527361/nIK2xTUE.jpg">
           
         </li>
          <li>
       <span>Sign in</span>
   <img src="http://www.dailyworldfacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/facts-about-cat-fallen-cat.jpg">
     
   </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So an image by default has a display type of inline-block. To enable it to be centered, include the following in your images css.

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

Comment: @Rob Nope you are mistaken. Most browsers interpret them as inline-blocks https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp. How else do you modify the imgs width and height if they are not blocks or int his case inline-blocks ;)

Comment: I am not mistaken but the definition has changed which is why I deleted my original comment to look it up. I haven't had to explain this for a while. <img> is a replaced element and will have its own "intrinsic" height and width making it outside the scope of CSS. It is not block level but it will behave inline and be manipulated like block level. I haven't re-read all that so I'll leave it as an exercise.

Comment: I forgot to add, just look in your browser's developer tools and you'll see the user agent setting is `display:inline`